# Passing an array to a function in reticulated Python

Tags: python, r, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to pass arguments to Python Function via R using the reticulate package. The Python function returns this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
ValueError: The initial_size argument must a 1D array of population size values
```

Here is my code block:

```
library("reticulate")


# Use the conda env with python, msprime, and tskit

use_condaenv(condaenv = "BioInfoTools")

# import the python libraries:

tskit <- reticulate::import("tskit")
msprime <- reticulate::import("msprime")
Ipython <- reticulate::import("IPython")
Scikit_allel <- reticulate::import("Scikit-allel")


###############################################################################
#Draw Priors from uniform distribution for Population size and Growth Rate:


popsize<- runif(10, min = 100, max = 1000000)

growthrate <- runif(10, min = -0.0005, max = 0.0005)

draws <- cbind(popsize, growthrate)

demography <- msprime$Demography$isolated_model(draws[1,1], growth_rate = draws[1,2])
```

The actual function giving the error is the `msprime$Demography$isolated_model(draws[1,1], growth_rate = draws[1,2])` call.

In addition to passing the values from `draws` I also passed an number as well.

`msprime$Demography$isolated_model(50000, growth_rate = -0.000315075)`

This also throws the same ValueError.

Any thoughts on how to pass properly pass values to this function?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it is worth noting that a 1d list in python with only one object in it is treated differently than passing that object to a function alone. I think you want to convert the values to a list, but I'm not sure how you do that in reticulate yet.

Comment: From what I can tell, `r_to_py(list(1))` returns a list with only one element in it, which I think is what you want. Try `msprime$Demography$isolated_model(list(draws[1,1]), growth_rate = list(draws[1,2]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to make a small change to your code. In particular, where you say:

```
demography <- msprime$Demography$isolated_model(draws[1,1], growth_rate = draws[1,2])
```

you need to say

```
demography <- msprime$Demography$isolated_model(list(draws[1,1]), growth_rate = list(draws[1,2]))
```

instead. After running this on my computer, I got this as the result:

```
> demography

Demography
╟  Populations
║  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
║  │ id │name   │description  │initial_size  │ growth_rate │  default_sampling_time│extra_metadata  │
║  ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
║  │ 0  │pop_0  │             │947223.3      │   5.7e-05   │                      0│{}              │
║  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
╟  Migration Matrix
║  ┌───────────────┐
║  │       │ pop_0 │
║  ├───────────────┤
║  │  pop_0│   0   │
║  └───────────────┘
╟  Events
║  ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
║  │  time│type  │parameters  │effect  │
║  ├───────────────────────────────────┤
║  └───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, by passing the value enclosed in `list()` does seem to solve the problem. Thanks!